# How to access QWebView's QScriptEngine?

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I want to access QScriptEngine::setProcessEventsInterval to make panels with long-running scripts more responsive.

How do I access it, QWebView, QWebPage, or QWebFrame don't seem to offer a way to get it? If this is not feasible, is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't think Qt WebKit bridge is based on QScriptEngine. Documentation says that "it is similar, but does not provide full Qt Script API for web applications."

Comment: It does seem like that. Thank you